# Whats the correct value to base the maximum number of CPU's to sched_setaffinity to?

Tags: c, linux, process-management

I have some confusion as to whats the correct value to use for the number of CPU's I can use to make a `CPU_SET` for a `sched_setaffinity` call on my system.

My `/proc/cpuinfo` file:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 37
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x2
cpu MHz     : 1199.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida arat dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 5056.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

In this file I found there are `processor` lines numbered 0-3, for "physical" processors (4 processors total).  I can get this value from `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)` but, there is also a line for `cpu cores` and each processor has 2.  I believe this represents the "logical" processors or hyperthreading that is accounted for.  Should I be using only the "physical" value or can I use the "logical" count?

I'm not clear on this because if I go to `/proc/PID/status` theres the line `Cpus_allowed_list` and that can range from 0-7 (8 processors total) but, I also wrote a script to call `taskset -c -p PID` for every "PID" running and this shows every process of having an affinity list of 0-3 max.

Comment: The number of CPU's (cores) that your computer has.

Comment: What is going on with `taskset` reporting that every process has an affinity list of 0-3, is this a default that most processes are created with?

Comment: Yes, processes are by default eligible to run on any processor.

Comment: So you both are saying that the "cores" here that can be set are the "physical" cores 0-3 and that the `/proc/PID/status` line of "Cpus_allowed_list: 0-7" half of these are considered "logical"(from hyperthreading) and can't be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hyper-threading you get 2 logical CPUs per core. This means that if one logical CPU stalls for any reason (cache miss, branch misprediction, instruction dependencies, etc) the core can execute instructions from the other logical CPU and isn't sitting there waiting/being wasted. In addition, typically the core is capable of doing more in parallel than a single logical CPU uses, so even without any of the (frequently common) stalls you still get benefits (by increasing utilisation of the core's resources). In this case; you want to use all logical CPUs.

For badly written multi-threaded software (software with significant scalability problems) the gains from hyper-threading can be lost by poor scalability. For example, the process might cause "cache line bouncing" (where cache lines are frequently being "bounced" between cores) and using affinity to reduce the number of cores can help. For another example, a core's RAM bandwidth might be the bottleneck (causing the process to get no benefit from hyper-threading), and using affinity to preventing the process from using both logical CPUs in each core can improve performance. For these cases; you only want to use some logical CPUs (but don't know which ones).

For single-threaded processes, it's not going to matter what you do.

Basically (assuming multi-threaded); the best setting for your process depends on the process; therefore you should run some tests to see how affinity effects your process.

**Misc. Notes**

When hyper-threading was first introduced (Netburst/Pentium 4) it was "less than ideal", and the schedulers in most operating systems weren't optimised to efficiently schedule load for hyper-threading (which made it even worse). This led to a lot of people thinking that hyper-threading is bad in lots of cases. Modern Intel CPUs do not have the same problems that Netburst/Pentium 4 had, and modern operating system schedulers do have optimisations for hyper-threading. This means that the old assumptions ("hyper-threading is probably bad") that were correct back then are mostly obsolete and wrong now.

Comment: @tijko: Heh - I'll add an explanation :-)

Comment: This is all helpful with learning more about the topic in general but, still doesn't answer what I was asking.

Comment: @tijko: The only correct answer is "the best setting for your process depends on the process; therefore you should run some tests to see how affinity effects your process".

Comment: @tijko: If you're not tuning the OS for a specific/important process, then you should probably set it to "all logical CPUs"

Comment: Which would be the hyperthreading 0-7 total?  If this is the case why does the `taskset` call show 0-3 for all processes?

Comment: @tijko: Your CPU is a dual core CPU - 2 logical CPUs per core with 2 cores means that there's a total of 4 logical CPUs (0 to 3).

Comment: Am I misunderstanding how to read the `/proc/cpuinfo` file, because the way I interpreted it was there are 0-3 "processors" listed and each have a line saying "cpu cores" = 2.  Which would give me a total of 8?

Comment: @tijko: You're misunderstanding it. If there were 8 logical CPUs then "/proc/cpuinfo" would list 8 logical CPUs (and http://ark.intel.com/products/50179/Intel-Core-i5-460M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz would say 4 cores). It's not 4 logical CPUs with 2 cores per logical CPU; it's 4 logical CPUs (with 2 cores in that physical chip). For my system (2 physical quad-core chips) it says 4 cores in the physical chip and lists 16 logical CPUs.

Comment: Why though the file `/proc/PID/status` and line "cpus_allowed_list" that shows 0-7 cpus?

Comment: @tijko: I don't know why you're getting that. It shouldn't matter though (the scheduler won't try to make threads run on CPUs that don't exist, so it won't do any harm)

Comment: I wrote a small script to parse all running processes `status`' file and __most__ show `cpus_allowed_list` being 0-7 **but**, I had another script that called `taskset -c -p PID` on all processes and most show 0-3.  This is and the reading the cpuinfo file is where my confusion is coming from...

Comment: @tijko: That would be confusing (Linux should probably limit affinity properly) :-)

Comment: I have left a comment under @tmp above to follow up with his response.

Answer (score 1):

The information from **man cpuset page**" regarding **Cpus_allowed_list**

> A cpuset defines a list of CPUs and memory nodes.**The CPUs of a system
>   include all the logical processing units on which a process can
>   execute, including, if present,multiple  processor  cores  within  a package and Hyper-Threads within a processor core**.  Memory nodes include all distinct banks of main
>   memory;
>          small and SMP systems typically have just one memory node that contains all the system's main memory, while NUMA (non-uniform memory
>          access) systems have multiple memory nodes
>
> Cpusets  are  integrated  with  the sched_setaffinity(2) scheduling
>   affinity mechanism and the mbind(2) and set_mempolicy(2) memory-
>          placement mechanisms in the kernel.  Neither of these mechanisms let a process make use of a CPU or memory node that is not 
>   allowed
>          by that process's cpuset.  If changes to a process's cpuset placement conflict with these other mechanisms, then cpuset placement
>   is
>          enforced even if it means overriding these other mechanisms.  The kernel accomplishes this overriding by  silently  restricting  the
>          CPUs  and  memory  nodes  requested by these other mechanisms to those allowed by the invoking process's cpuset.  This can result in
>          these other calls returning an error, if for example, such a call ends up requesting an empty set of CPUs  or  memory  nodes, 
>   after
>          that request is restricted to the invoking process's cpuset.

**Additional Information regarding cpuset** and how kernel handle request to changed/moved
from one cpuset to another.

Every process in the system belongs to exactly one cpuset.A process is confined to only run on the CPUs in the cpuset  it  belongs to,  and  to  allocate  memory only on the memory nodes in that cpuset.  When a process fork(2)s, the child process is placed in the
same cpuset as its parent. **With sufficient privilege, a process may be moved from one** cpuset to another and the  allowed  CPUs  and memory nodes of an existing cpuset may be changed.

So I think if you are getting the Cpus_allowed_list value to be 8, that probably means that your machine is 4 core and each core hyper thread enable. SO logically it becomes 4*2.
Hence we should go by logical CPU's and not the physical CPU's while calling sched_setaffinity() and we should check the return value if it fails to get the more information regarding why it failed.

Comment: I am getting invalid arguments when setting the cpu_set regardless if its set to 7 cpus or 3 cpus for **some** of the processes but, not all.  Although the ones that don't return an error are set with 7 cores in the cpu_set and `taskset` is still reporting that theirs is set to 0-3???

Comment: @tijko: It depends on many factor like the parent cpuset,sufficent privileges and all.I do not idea about taskset command but once the sched_setaffinity() completes successfully,it ensures that cpuset has set to the a particular logical CPU which user has provided.

Comment: I have proper permissions here but, I'm not sure about parent cpuset.  I haven't put together `get_schedaffinity` yet, I've just used `taskset` to see if the output was still the same.  I do get 1-3 now(instead of 0-3 like before the call) for the processes that are able to make the call successfully but, like I mentioned the mask is set to 1-7?

Comment: Follow up:  I did indeed get a set of 3 cpus back from one of the processes successfully set to a cpu_set of 7(which didn't return an error).  I also did a `strace taskset -c -p PID` which shows it is making a call to `sched_getaffinity` too and getting the same data.  So right now I can see in `/proc/PID/status` on line `Cpus_allowed_list` it shows 0-7 as being "allowed" and I make a call to `sched_setaffinity` with a cpuset that has 7 cpus in it and this doesn't return an error but, after `get_schedaffinity` shows there are only 3 in the processes set???